# Excluding fonts from the asset pipeline in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts, asset-pipeline

I'm currently struggling with Firefox's CORS same domain policy when using CloudFront to serve assets. I've tried using the [Font Assets gem](https://github.com/ericallam/font_assets) without any luck.

I thought about having something like this in my stylesheet:

```
src: url('<%= Rails.application.config.local_static_url %>/belinda-webfont.eot');
```

and the config value

```
config.local_static_url = '//mydomain.com'
```

I'm keeping the fonts inside the app/assets/fonts folder.
I'm not sure how to make it work, because the fonts get copied to S3, and get the digest added to them.

Is there a way of keeping the fonts on Heroku and serving them from the /assets folder?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have assets you don't want to go through the pipeline, put them in `/public` instead of `/assets`. Then they'll be served as static files with no magic.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate files and include it to your main layout with normal `<link>` tag. This post might be helpful: http://thelazylog.com/posts/resolve-cors-fonts-issue-on-firefox-and-now-chrome-too-with-rails-assets-pipeline